# issue in a build whith gcloud.run. deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to build pipeline using GitLab for deploy on Google Cloud.

Everything works fine, except the gcloud command for deploy.

I have the following error :
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account XXXX@YYYYYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com (or it may not exist)

I searched for a solution in stack overflow and added 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' using gcloud command :
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YYYYY --member='serviceAccount:XXXXX@YYYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'

The role is added to the service account, but the deploy still fail.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the new error?

Answer (score 1):

When you create certain Google Cloud resources, you have the option to attach a service account. The attached service account acts as the identity of any jobs running on the resource, allowing the jobs to authenticate to Google Cloud APIs.

For most Google Cloud services, users need permission to impersonate a service account in order to attach that service account to a resource. This means that the user needs the `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission on the service account.

I suggest you to read this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas) and check if you have implemented all needed to impersonate the service account.